# Can I use IF in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I made a table and four sequences. (one sequence for a column, and three sequence for a column.)

```
CREATE TABLE abc (
  whole_number VARCHAR2(100) primary key,
  board_number VARCHAR2(100),
  board VARCHAR2(100),
  content VARCHAR2(100)
);
CREATE SEQUENCE whole_seq
  MINVALUE 1
  NOMAXVALUE
  INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 
;

CREATE SEQUENCE notify_seq
  MINVALUE 1
  NOMAXVALUE
  INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 
;
CREATE SEQUENCE product_seq
  MINVALUE 1
  NOMAXVALUE
  INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 
;
CREATE SEQUENCE guide_seq
  MINVALUE 1
  NOMAXVALUE
  INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 
;
```

I want to create a Procedure that adds whole_seq for whole_number column at every row,
and guide_seq for board_number column if the board column gets 'guide'.
and notify_seq for board_number column if the board column gets 'notify'.

One procedure for whole_number column is made now.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER whole_number_trigger 
  BEFORE INSERT 
  ON abc FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
  SELECT whole_seq INTO :new.whole_number FROM dual;
END;  
/
```

Can someone help me make a procedure that gets different sequence depending on the value of board column in ORACLE?
Also, is there any way to add string 'Board_' before the sequence number of whole_number column?

Comment: This is a question which you could easily have answered for yourself [by reading the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/controlstatements.htm#LNPLS004)

Comment: Prefixing the primary key with 'Board_' is a really bad idea. It clutters the key and requires an additional check constraint to ensure the number element remains unique. It does explain why your key columns area  string datatype rather than a numeric. There is a better way to do this but it's a different answer. Please ask a separate question.

Comment: Oh and having two difference sequences populate the same column is another bad idea. A sequence is just a monotonically incrementing series: it has no information. So there's no way to distinguish one arbitrary number from another. Again, if you really want to do this there are workarounds, but broadly it seems like you need to reconsider your data model.

Comment: ummm. I was having same idea at some points of what you said. Thanks. I will think about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER whole_number_trigger 
  BEFORE INSERT 
  ON abc FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
  SELECT 'Board_' || whole_seq.nextval INTO :new.whole_number FROM dual;
  IF :new.board = 'guide' THEN 
    SELECT guide_seq.nextval INTO :new.board_number FROM dual;
  ELSIF   :new.board = 'notify' THEN 
    SELECT notify_seq.nextval INTO :new.board_number FROM dual;
  END IF;
END;  
/
```

Comment: no need for the selects; you can do `:new.whole_number := guide_seq.nextval;` (at least in 11.2 and above; can't recall if it's possible in earlier versions)

Comment: Thanks, Now, I can understand how to use IF based on your code. :)