# (Oracle) IN condition in IF statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to check, if value of variable is equal to one of two values. Can i use IN condition there?

Example:

```
if (proc_stat in (ap_public.ap_tool.c_status_array(3), ap_public.ap_tool.c_status_array(1))) then
```

Comment: Well, yes.  Is there a problem?

Comment: Did you even try it ?

Comment: At least you know you can use `if` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40354686/can-i-use-if-in-pl-sql

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can. 
For example:

```
DECLARE
        vcA VARCHAR2(1) := 'A';
        vcB VARCHAR2(1) := 'B';
BEGIN
        IF vcA IN ('A', 'E') THEN
                -- This will get printed. 
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('True');
        END IF;

        IF vcB IN ('A', 'E') THEN
                -- This will not get printed. 
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('False');
        END IF;
END;
/
```